How to create a Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ColorFormat
Creating PowerPoint presentations in C# Visual Studio, I needed to create "colorFormat" object but I realize there is not constructor.
I have this code example in "C:\myPowerPoint\" for C# Windows Forms .NET
I have added from Reference Manager>COM>Type Libraries the assembly reference "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" (Version 2.8), or also from NuGet: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint" (Version 15.0.4420.1018) added to my project...
I have created Form1, and button1:
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using State = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myPowerPoint
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = null;
        PowerPoint.Presentation ppt = null;
        PowerPoint.Slides slides = null;
        PowerPoint.Slide slide = null;
        PowerPoint.ColorFormat colorFormat = null;
        readonly float u = 72.0f; // Inches
        int k = 0; // Loop index

        public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a temporary PowerPoint Application to interact with
            pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();
            ppt = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(State.msoFalse);
            ppt.Slides.Application.Caption = "My First PowerPoint";
            slides = ppt.Slides; // pptApplication.Presentations.Slides

            // First Slide - Blank
            slide = slides.AddSlide(1, ppt.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText]);
            slide.Layout = PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank;

            // First Shape - FlowchartTerminator
            slide.Shapes.AddShape(Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartTerminator, 6.61f * u, 4.57f * u, 0.77f * u, 0.23f * u);
            int i = slide.Shapes.Count;
            colorFormat = applyMyTemplate(slide.Shapes[i].Fill.ForeColor);
            slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow";
            slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 5.0f;
            slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = Office.MsoVerticalAnchor.msoAnchorMiddle;
            slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = Office.MsoHorizontalAnchor.msoAnchorCenter;
            slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Box";
            slide.Shapes[i].Top = 4.57f * u;
            slide.Shapes[i].Width = 0.77f * u;
            slide.Shapes[i].Fill.ForeColor = colorFormat; // Here
            slide.Shapes[i].Line.ForeColor = colorFormat; // Here2
            slide.Shapes[i].Shadow.ForeColor = colorFormat; // Here3
            slide.Shapes[i].Height = 0.23f * u;
            slide.Shapes[i].Left = 6.61f * u;

            // Save and close PowerPoint
            string path = @"C:\myPowerPoint\";
            string file = "Presentation_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() + ".ppt";
            file = file.Replace(":", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace(" ", "_");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path + file)) System.IO.File.Delete(path + file);
            ppt.SaveAs(path + file, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
            ppt.Close();
        }

        private PowerPoint.ColorFormat applyMyTemplate(PowerPoint.ColorFormat colorFormat)
        {
            // Do some processing... Just an example, ignore it
            k++;
            if (k == 1) { colorFormat.SchemeColor = PowerPoint.PpColorSchemeIndex.ppAccent1; }
            if (k == 2) { colorFormat.SchemeColor = PowerPoint.PpColorSchemeIndex.ppAccent2; }
            if (k == 3) { colorFormat.SchemeColor = PowerPoint.PpColorSchemeIndex.ppAccent3; k = 0; }
            return colorFormat; 
        }
    }
}

Exception due to colorFormat need to be defined
So I need to know how to create colorFormat.
The question is resolved when "colorFormat" is properly defined in "slide.Shapes[i].Fill.ForeColor = colorFormat;" so the code will generate a Power Point file. Such presentation will show the backcolor in "Box" defined by colorFormat.
Edited: Nov. 24, 2024. I have replaced BackColor by ForeColor as:
slide.Shapes[i].Fill.ForeColor = colorFormat; // Here

Edited: Nov. 26, 2024. I need to reformulate the question since looks like I am asking about RGB color but, as Victor pointed out below, I assumed ColorFormat was a Class but an Interface. So, I have updated the code where I want to apply my template. Is it the right solution to the question? Please, the applyMyTemplate() function is just a functional example and it is not relevant to the question, do not try to optimize.

What does the documentation say? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.fill

@iakobski, the question is about how to define ColorFormat object that can be used with AnimationSettings, FillFormat, Font, LineFormat, ShadowFormat, SlideShowSettings, SlideShowView, and ThreeDFormat as per link but the question is more programmatically since the example is for VBA, not for C#. Thanks

It's the same in C#. You can't define a ColorFormat object, it's an interface, but you can set its values, as per the documentation. For example: `var colorFormat = slide.Shapes[i].Fill.ForeColor; colorFormat.RGB = RGB(128, 0, 0);

Actually the ForeColor is the COM interface. Therefore, you can use methods and  properties it provides.
For example, to definition the shape fill color:
// The code based on the fragment from the question above 

using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

...

var shape = slide.Shapes.AddShape(Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartTerminator, 6.61f * u, 4.57f * u, 0.77f * u, 0.23f * u);
  
shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 127, 0).ToArgb();        
shape.Height = 0.23f * u;
shape.Left = 6.61f * u;
...  


Any another method returning the System.Drawing.Color type might be used to obtain  required color. For example:
shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("BurlyWood").ToArgb();


Victor, thanks, but the question is not about handling color, it is about how to define ColorFormat object. So, the question is more programmatically. In your answer, your example only define RGB property but ForeColor (and others as link) has many other properties like: Brightness, ObjectThemeColor, RGB, SchemeColor, TintAndShade, etc. The question still open, how to define colorFormat object.

@JoshuaTristancho: Your question is tagged as [c#]. The documentation you are referencing related to VBA. In the VBA this called object,
but in c# terms this is interface, that you can use to communicate with an object.

@JoshuaTristancho: The data described in ColorFormat is part of some object (referenced by PowerPoint.Shape.Parent property) that you will not access directly.
And this type of object is created by calling method PowerPoint.AddShape() in your code. After the shape is created you can only use the PowerPoint.Shape.FillFormat interface to change any properties that related to the shape fill format and have the setter: including ColorFomat.

@JoshuaTristancho:
The documentation you are referenced describes all these properties list.
In other words, to fix puncture in a tire I'm not going to by a new car and then replace the tire. I just using tools to replace the tire. I hope this was clear enough.

Thanks victor, so my initial assumption based on the VBA documentation was wrong since ColorFormat is not an object as stated in the documentation but an interface.
